# Probability density function of the square of the standard normal variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

The question: It's given that $Z = N(0,1)$ (the standard normal random variable), $Y= Z^2$. Calcualte the probability density function of Y.

I tried the following: ($F_Y$ is the distribution function of Y)

$F_Y(t) = P(Y\le t) = P(Z^2 \le t) = P(-\sqrt{t} \le Z \le \sqrt{t}) = \int_{-\sqrt{t}}^{\sqrt{t}} f_Z(x)dx = \int_{-\sqrt{t}}^{\sqrt{t}} (1/\sqrt{2\pi})e^{-x^2/2}dx$

But now I'm stuck since this integral doesn't have an antiderivative. What can I do to proceed?

Thanks

Comment: You don't need an anti-derivative. What do you know about differentiating an integral with respect to its boundaries?

Comment: i don't know how to do it actually, never seen a case like this before. I only know how to do it without the boundaries.

Comment: The factor in the density of $Z$ should also be $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$.

Comment: Edited, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By symmetry, the fundamental theorem of calculus and the chain rule, you get for all $t>0$

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{-\sqrt{t}}^{\sqrt{t}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}dx=2\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^{\sqrt{t}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}dx= \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-t/2} \cdot \frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}.$$

Since $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}$, this is equal to

$$ \frac{(1/2)^{(1/2)}}{\Gamma(1/2)}e^{-(1/2)t}t^{(1/2)-1}.$$

Do you know this expression?

Comment: Thanks, learnt something new :)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: I do not know this gamma sign (and in particular don't know this expression)

Comment: OK, I thought it might have come up in your probability course. $\Gamma$ denotes the gamma function and the expression above is the density of the gamma distribution with parameters $(1/2,1/2)$, also known as the $\chi^2$-distribution. This makes the whole result a little more "catchy". ;-)